# Mortar recommendation for repointing this older stone chimney

Tags: mortar, chimney

[image]Which type of mortar or product would you think most appropriate for doing some repointing on this chimney?

I've been reading about using mortar that is too hard for the stones. I'm worried I will pick the wrong product. Ideas? Much appreciated.

More images here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAgnC.jpg

Comment: i know this is DIY, but to me, the risk/reward ratio of experimenting on this is way too high; consult an expert.

Comment: Are you planning on using the fireplace? I would want a full inspection and evaluation, I removed a similar fire hazard from my current home, it passed the VA inspection but it had no liner and did need repointing I ripped it out it was beautiful but a huge liability (one of my dads companies that I worked in was a chimney sweep co so I know what to look for.) natural stone if not lined should be capped to prevent it from being used unless a insert with a liner or stack is installed.

Comment: Yes. Looks like its not a DIY. :/. Do want to use it.